# How do I get this result: table(Team Name, <numbers of being champions>, <numbers of being sub-champions>)?

Tags: sql, subquery

```
select Name, (
select count(Season)
from Team t, Finale f
where t.ID_Team=f.Champion
) = Champions,
(   
select count(Season)
from Team t, Finale f
where t.ID_Team=f.SubChampion
) = SubChampions
from Team
```

If i run them as separate selects i get the data i'm supposed to get but only in the format: Team Name, champions and Team name, sub-champions.
How can i join them into a single table in the format explained in the question? The solution is supposed to be done using sub queries.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a proper database tag, and learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: thank you, I solved it, I just didn't know the rules how the sub queries work.